# Do SQL Server Express Editions support CLR procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express, sql-clr

Do SQL Server Express Editions (2005, and 2008) have support for installing, enabling  and running CLR Stored procedures and functions.

Comment: [Yes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

Comment: I guess there might be specific issues with using this on Express though as it only has 1GB of memory to play with anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, [the Express editions do support CLR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Programmability) integration. The link is for the latest version, but if you switch to 2008 you will see it is supported there too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is supported.

A note of caution, though: to support 2005, you have to be *extremely* careful to thoroughly test your application on 2005, because some of the functionality is limited compared to 2008+, and the differences are buried in the documentation.

For example, we had to deploy a user-defined aggregate function for our database, which is supposed to be 2005+ compatible, but found that the `MaxByteSize` attribute cannot be set to `-1` (unlimited) on 2005 (and we require it to be `-1` for our purposes). We were able to restrict deployment of the assembly to 2008+ for that feature -- you may not be as lucky.